# How to tell if an image contains a "handwritten signature"?

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a form (with a line drawn at the bottom right for signing the form) that is scanned into a TIF format (black/white).

Some people filling out the form may sign on it and some don't. So how can I tell if the scanned image contains a signature on it? Any algorithm suggested or any existing framework or libraries that can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Find a pixel on the sign band that is not white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code I've used in the past for checking for a signature. It assumes that an image has a `Bytes per pixel` of 3.

The `MAX_BLACK_VALUE` number comes from the max value for a colour of a pixel (255) multiplied by 3 (because there is a bytes per pixel of 3) then halved.

The code works by summing up the number of pixels in the signature image, and if it passes the `MinPixelCount` returning true, i.e. a Signature has been detected. Else it will return false.

The code also makes use of `Lockbits` a method to make image processing faster, if `java` has a similar method just make sure to always call `UnlockBits` as I have in the `finally` statement.

```
private const int MAX_BLACK_VALUE = 382; // ((255 * 3) / 2) rounded down

private bool CheckForSignature(string SignatureFile, int MinPixelCount)
{
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SignatureFile))
    {
        int nBytesPerPixel = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat) / 8;
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        try
        {
            byte[] baPixels = new byte[bitmapData.Stride * bitmap.Height];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, baPixels, 0, baPixels.Length);

            int nBlackPixels = 0;
            for (int h = 0; h < bitmap.Height; h++)
            {
                int nCurrentLine = h * bitmapData.Stride;
                for (int w = 0; w < (bitmap.Width * nBytesPerPixel); w += nBytesPerPixel)
                {
                    int nBlue = baPixels[nCurrentLine + w];
                    int nGreen = baPixels[nCurrentLine + w + 1];
                    int nRed = baPixels[nCurrentLine + w + 2];

                    if (nBlue + nGreen + nRed <= MAX_BLACK_VALUE)
                    {
                        nBlackPixels++;
                        if (nBlackPixels >= MinPixelCount)
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

p.s I realise this is a `java` question but I only know `C#` but you should be able to convert it.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the value of `MinPixelCount`?

Comment: @Steven MinPixelCount is a parameter passed into the function, it can easily be changed to a percentage though, although this would impact performance as you would need to check the majority of the pixles

Answer (score 5):

You could threshold the image (turn it into black and white) and sum up how many black pixels are inside the region of your box. You could use a percentage of how many pixels were filled as a rudimentary test for how 'drawn in' your signature field is. The drawback with this is that when defining your threshold, you risk missing out lighter signatures when the threshold is too high, or misinterpreting empty boxes as being filled in (too low). Additionally the colour of pen used would be a factor to take into account. Though, we're lucky in this application since the stark contrast between a plain white box and handwriting will work in our favour.

A similar approach could use cross-correlation to calculate the difference between your blank signature box and one that's supposed to have been signed, to gain a value for the difference between the two. It's likely that boxes that are signed will have a significantly larger error from those that are not.

You're probably familiar with Optical Character Recognition (OCR), a machine-vision approach which allows computers to meaningfully interpret symbols, though with human handwriting this is quite difficult to do as it requires the system to be 'trained' as handwriting can vary so much. This problem is worsened by the fact that people like to have stylistic flare with their own signatures. This approach is likely overkill however, since you don't actually need to register every single character of the signature within your software.

You can also use morphological (shape changing) techniques such as dilating, eroding, or opening and closing to try and exaggerate the intensities of regions within your signature box. We don't have to worry about morphing the shapes of your data, since we only really care if they're there or not. Then you could use a blob count to see whether enough are detected within the bounds.

You should try experimenting with different approaches available to you using an open image processing toolkit such as [ImageJ](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/download.html), which comes pre-packaged with some high-level tools you can take advantage of in determining which gives you the best indication. The only limit is your creativity!

Comment: Feel free to convert my answer to java for the OPs benefit seeing as you have great insight on the topic

Comment: Thanks Alex. Would you mind giving me more info/hints on image cross-correlation? :) This approach sounds interesting to me..

Comment: @Steven Just so you're aware my answer is the C# approach to Alex's top paragraph

Answer (score -2):

I would have a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org).